# How to find number of occurences and max length of a 1's in a vector of 0's and 1's with Excel formulas

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

Say I have a vector of 0's and 1's like this:

[image: Vector of 0's and 1's]

I would like to find the number of "runs" for a sequence of 1's (in this case "runs" = 2 -- there are two times where 1's turn on and turn off). I would also like to find the max length of the run (in this case, it is 3).

I was able to find the number of runs using by first calculating the difference and then running a `SUMIF` (see below), but have not found a succinct way of determining the max length of the run.

[image: # of Runs]

---

### More examples with expected results

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the largest sequence you can use this array formula, so confirm with CTRL, SHIFT and ENTER.

`=MAX(FREQUENCY(IF((A1:A10=1)*(A1:A10<>""),ROW(A1:A10)),IF(A1:A10=0,ROW(A1:A10))))`

Comment: That's nice. I was beating myself up with array formulas and couldn't get this going.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with `Countifs()`. A list of 1s and 0s in cells A1:A13 could be counted for runs of 1s using:

```
=COUNTIFS(A2:A14, 0,  A1:A13, 1) + COUNTIFS(A2:A14, "",  A1:A13, 1)
```

[image]

We are just counting the number of times a cell is 0 where the previous row was also 1. We add that second `countifs()` in there to catch that last row where it ends with a NULL `""` valued cell.

Comment: This is great for the number of runs, but what about the max length?

Comment: @JasonAizkalns one question per post.  This answered the main question, please ask another for the second.

Comment: Honestly I didn't see that part of the question. I think it would be worth asking as a second question as well as it's an entirely different animal. This way folks searching for similar questions in the future will get right to the answer they need for their specific question.

Comment: Will do @JNevill -- I only posted "two" because I already solved the first part (granted, your solution is more elegant). Welp nevermind, looks like @SJR got it with a `MAX(FREQUENCY(IF` array formula.

Comment: That is very clever, I was trying to think of all sorts of complicated array formulae!